# MFC compile error using classes built in C++ console app

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to build a fractal application in MFC using code that I have written in a C++ console application. I have a created all the same classes in the MFC application and I clicked build (I wasn't expecting it to work)

Anyway it complains a lot about the RGB.h class and the RGB.cpp class.
Do I need to change something in the configuration of the project?

If I build the console application it works fine, but clearly there are differences when trying to use the classes in an MFC application.

Just wanted to know if there is anything I can do about these two errors as I'm not sure where to start with them.

**RGB.cpp**

compiler error: expected a ;

```
RGB::RGB(double r, double g, double b) : r(r), g(g), b(b) {}
```

**RGB.h**

Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ')' before '|'

```
RGB(double r, double g, double b);
```

Comment: Sometimes you need to check the previous line for parsing errors like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with the code posted as such. But [RGB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rgb) is a macro, declared in wingdi.h, that gets pulled in when including Windows.h. It is defined like this:

```cpp
#define RGB(r,g,b) ((COLORREF)(((BYTE)(r)|((WORD)((BYTE)(g))<<8))|(((DWORD)(BYTE)(b))<<16)))
```

This preprocessor macro clashes with the symbol used for the type. It's easiest to use a different symbol for the type, e.g. `rgb`.

Comment: you sir are a genius! I never knew that wingdi.h was using RGB Macro. Changed it to RGBb and now it builds.